# Is there a way to completely disable RMI in a java application?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, rmi

In our application remote Procedure call is solved with an own netty based command dispatcher system. We have a lot of modules (about 20) and I want to run all modules in separate jvm-s. My problem is, that RMI spawns about 17 threads for each JVM. I do not need RMI at all (as far as I know).

Can I completely disable RMI for a jvm? Or at least configure it in a way that it does not use this many threads?

Comment: If you're not using RMI, those threads perform no work. This sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom. With 20 jvm running on one machine there are 340 unused threads. This already can be seen on the load. I really do not understand why RMI needs 17(!) unused threads. This is 'postmature' optimization :)

Comment: @Szobi So there are 340 sleeping threads, the only way they can have an influence on your performance is if you are running under 32bit Java and are running out of virtual address space. If that's not the case, what exactly do you think those threads will do to you?

Comment: @Szobi Perhaps you should provide some evidence as to the load you are observing -- profiling results from VisualVM or a thread dump or similar.

Comment: I do not want this question to go in a 'is it premature optimization' direction. I would like to know if RMI can be switched off or not. If I do not need a feature of java, why do I have to use it?

Comment: What threads are these? RMI doesn't spawn any threads unless somebody is actually using RMI. Do you have any evidence that these threads are actually RMI threads? What are their names? A typical JVM has several service threads running by default. For example, running a program that does nothing but sleep on my system (Mac 7u25 64-bit) has 11 threads, including a few GC threads, a signal handler, a finalizer, a reference handler, etc., plus the main thread. If you're doing actual work in a JVM, 17 threads is quite plausible, and this might have nothing to do with RMI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StuartMarks is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180161/is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-rmi-in-a-java-application/19191130#comment28391611_19180161). RMI doesn't start any threads until you use it.

Possibly you are using it in some way of which you are unaware, e.g. JMX?

Answer (score 6):

You are most likely looking at your JVMs with a monitoring application, right? Well: these monitoring applications *use* RMI. So you will see always RMI threads within your monitoring application, profiler, etc. And you will always see them using some amount of CPU time. Just as gathering profiling information does not work without transporting these information (via RMI) to your tool. You can implement your own transportation protocol and direct the management beans to use it but I doubt that you can save enough resources to return your development costs.

If you don’t use any RMI, RMI won’t start any threads. But if you are using it, even if you aren’t aware of this, disabling RMI implies that your software will not work any more.