# init Jvm with least possible threads

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm

I have a simple `java` hello world program with a `sleep`

Java Code:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(100000l);
     }
   }
```

compile using javac

```
javac Main.java
```

Run using

```
java Main
```

Now if i see in `jvisualvm` i see this 11 threads.
**Why are RMI thread started ?

How do i start a jvm with only the essential threads ?**

why i want to do this is because constraint by the `nproc` limit in `limit.conf` and want to run maximun jvm concurrently. Also these jvm are short live.

i am using oracle jdk 7

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the rmi threads aren't only started because you're using visualvm? That one has to talk to the jvm you're interested in which probably involves starting some threads. I'd try a less invasive method to count threads. But yes there will be singe extra threads that you can't get rid of (finalizer, gc,..)

Answer (score 2):

Would you believe me if I told you none of those threads really mean anything to you?

They're all either part of the infrastructure VisualVM uses to talk to your program, or part of the JVM itself. None of them can be eliminated safely, nor should they; they're doing VM background tasks so you needn't worry about them.

Basically, don't worry about it, the overhead they give in programs much larger than a hello-world are meaningless.

If you're curious as to what a couple of them are, the `reference manager` simply manages the objects currently in memory, and the `finalizer` is part of the garbage collector. In short, things you shouldn't worry about.

Comment: as mentioned in question as well..."why i want to do this is because constraint by the nproc limit in limit.conf and want to run maximun jvm concurrently. Also these jvm are short live."...so "Would you believe me if I told you none of those threads really mean anything to you?" .. No i think they do mean to me..

Comment: Maybe he is telling you ... that if you have such explicit requirements, using the J2 SE isn't the right approach?

Comment: What I'm saying is that most of those threads *need* to be there, and they don't do hardly any work or take up very much memory space if you're not using them actively, so unless you're on a very, *very* specific set of constraints (need to run 1024 JVMs in parallel on a Raspberry Pi or something else with ridiculously little overhead to spare) you probably needn't care. ALSO, it's better to use a thread pool and ONE copy of the JVM than to try and run each "short-lived" operation in a separate JVM instance. The overhead will be much, much lower.

Answer (score 1):

See [Is there a way to completely disable RMI in a java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180161/is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-rmi-in-a-java-application/19191130#comment28391611_19180161)

Unless you use RMI, your JVM will not start RMI threads. 'Short lived' JVMs, though, is probably not an idea that will work out well, with or without the perceived overhead of RMI threads

Answer (score 1):

RMI threads are started on demand only when you connect to JVM with VisualVM, JConsole or a similar tool. As to other threads, there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706865/3448419) how to reduce their number.